# Android service destroyed, but not infinite loop

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin, intentservice

Everybody!

I have a problem with my app (Xamarin.Android).
I'm trying to write service which should scan Bluetooth devices:

```
[Service]
internal class BluetoothService : IntentService
{
    ...

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // Thats not working...
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {

        _bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

        ScanLeDeviceInLoop(true);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }


    private async void ScanLeDeviceInLoop(bool enable)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            if (enable == _loopScanningEnabled)
                return;

            _loopScanningEnabled = enable;

            while (_loopScanningEnabled)
            {
                _container.Clear();
                _bluetoothAdapter.StartLeScan(_leScanCallback);

                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)_scanPeriod.TotalMilliseconds));

                _bluetoothAdapter.StopLeScan(_leScanCallback);

                OnScanCompleted();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After OnStartCommand and ScanLeDeviceInLoop service call onDestroy. But I want to keep this service alive (thread with scanning is alive, but service not) and call StopService from UI to stop scanning. But I can't due to service is already stopped.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` are designed to perform finite units of work asynchronously.

> They handle asynchronous requests (expressed as `Intents`) on demand.
>   Clients send requests through `StartService(Intent)` calls; the
>   service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a
>   worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.
>
> You should not override `OnStartCommand` method for your
>   `IntentService`. Instead, override `OnHandleIntent(Intent)`, which the
>   system calls when the `IntentService` receives a start request.

In your situation service probably stops because he finished all the work in `OnHandleIntent` which is none.

I recommend you to use `Service` class, but remember that you should create your new thread manually, because `Service` unlike `IntentService` working on the main thread

Comment: If will use Service (in another thread) instead IntentService, will that Service work after app will be killed?

Comment: yes, if you use StartForeground method to start service